# Set the First Element to x:Null (a Xaml Question)

Tags: xaml, syntax

I created a custom Collection property for a XAML control:

```
class MyClass : DependencyObject
{
    public ObservableCollection<object> MyCollection
    {
        get { return GetValue(MyCollectionProperty) as ObservableCollection<object>;}
        set { SetValue(MyCollectionProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependecyProperty MyCollectionProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(MyCollection), typeof(ObservableCollection<object>), new PropertyMetadata(new ObservableCollection<object>()));
}
```

but when I try to add elements to it in XAML:

```
<local:MyClass
    *snip*>
    <local:MyClass.MyCollection>
        <x:Null/> // this causes a crash because it sets my collection to null
        <Button/>
        <x:Null/>
    </local:MyClass.MyCollection>
</local:MyClass>
```

I get an XamlParseException - "...property has already been set ..." I think that what happens is the parser interprets the above code as a request to set my entire collection to null, then tries to set it to Button, then sets it to null. If Button is first then the Button and the nulls are added to my default list with no problem.

**What is the correct syntax for setting the first element in a list to null in XAML?** The Content Properties and Collection Syntax Combined section of [XAML Syntax in Detail](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/xaml-syntax-in-detail) is the most useful reference I have found so far. My guess is that it will be some sort of Markup Extension, but everything I've tried gives the same sort of error.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to remove the setter from your MyCollection property - without an available setter, the XAML parser interprets your collection as an Implicit collection (one that *can't* be set, but *can* be added to.) This means that the parser **won't** interpret your initial x:Null as a null collection, and will instead add it to your existing list.

From [XAML Syntax in Detail](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/xaml-syntax-in-detail):

> An implicit collection element creates a member in the logical tree representation, even though it does not appear in the markup as an element. Usually the constructor of the parent type performs the instantiation for the collection that is one of its properties, and the initially empty collection becomes part of the object tree.